# C++: boost::asio: async_resolve() doesn't work (with lambda functions), but resolve() works

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, boost-asio

Based on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) example, I have this synchronous initialization part of my program:

```
io_service = new boost::asio::io_service;
resolver   = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver(*io_service);
query      = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(data.serverAddress.c_str(),data.serverPort.c_str());
iterator   = resolver->resolve(*query);
//...
```

Now this works fine without any problem, except that if there's no connection, the call `resolver->resolve(*query);` blocks infinitely. To resolve this, I decided to use `resolver->async_resolve(*query);` instead. So I wrote the following code to act synchronously with lambda functions, so the following replaces the last statement of the former code:

```
    boost::system::error_code queryError;
    boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&,const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator&)> queryLambda =
            [&querySuccess,&queryError,this]
            (const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator& it)
    {std::cout<<"Success!"<<std::endl;querySuccess=1;iterator=it;queryError=errorCode;};

    resolver->async_resolve(*query,queryLambda);


    int timeout = 10000;
    int totalTime = 0;
    int timeWaitStep = 1000;

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout<<"Trying to connect..."<<std::endl;
        sleep(timeWaitStep);
        if(querySuccess)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            totalTime += timeWaitStep;
            std::cout<<totalTime<<std::endl;
            if(totalTime > timeout)
            {
                throw std::domain_error("Unable to connect to server. Make sure you have a valid connection.");
            }
        }
    }
```

While the synchronous code connects in an instant, the asynchronous code never connects. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `run` work somewhere, using `io_service::run` function, or `io_service::poll`. And BTW, if you want to `resolve` with timeout, you should use `deadline_timer` and `async_wait`.

Answer (score 3):

In Boost.Asio issuing an asynchronous operation means that you schedule it to be called inside the `io_service`; all these operations will not happen unless you tell the `io_service` that it should start polling the network, performing scheduled operations and calling your callbacks. This is what methods like `io_service::poll` and `io_service::run` do.

The simpliest way is to call `io_service::run` just after you call `async_resolve`:

```
...
resolver->async_resolve(*query,queryLambda);

io_service->run();
```